# hide link if it matched the value of a array

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I have a function which fire's a function for each '#tree ol li' the tree is a list of file's and directories which are generated from a php script..
my thought was to see if '#tree ol li a' the anchor element's value ends with a specific extension name, and hide it. so i tried to make this script.. but it is not working..
can anyone help me find the spot where I am wrong?..

```
function checkstuff(){
i = 0;
$("#tree ol li").each(function(){

i++;
console.log(i);
var temp_val = $(this).children("a").attr("href");
var temp_val2 = temp_val.substr(temp_val.length - 4);
console.log(temp_val2);
var extArr = [".mp3",".wav",".m4a"];
if(temp_val2 == extArr[i]){
console.log(extAttr[i] + "WELL this should have worked..");
$(this).hide();
}; 
});
```

Comment: i know my loop is a bit messed up but i made it like that on purpose.

Comment: could you specify in how far it is not working?

Comment: everything seems fine till the console.log(temp_val2); as it is firing the correct value's.

Comment: what do you mean, it is firing the correct values? could you maybe show what you get, and explain what you would like to get instead?

Comment: Are you trying to hide a link, if its extension is either .mp3 or .wav or .m4a ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
function checkstuff(){
    i = 0;
    $("#tree ol li").each(function(){

    i++;
    console.log(i);
    var temp_val = $(this).children("a").attr("href");
    var temp_val2 = temp_val.substr(temp_val.length - 4);
    console.log(temp_val2);
    var extArr = [".mp3",".wav",".m4a"];
    if($.inArray(temp_val2 ,extArr[i])>-1){
    console.log(extAttr[i] + "WELL this should have worked..");
    $(this).hide();
    }; 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function checkstuff() {
  $("#tree ol li").each(function() {


    var temp_val = $(this).children("a").attr("href");
    var temp_val2 = temp_val.substr(temp_val.length - 4);    
    console.log(temp_val2);
    var extArr = [".mp3", ".wav", ".m4a"];
    for (i = 0; i < extArr.length; i++) {
      if (temp_val2 == extArr[i]) {
        console.log(extArr[i] + "WELL this should have worked..");
        $(this).hide();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Here is your working script

Comment: thanks! it works! it saved me a lot of headache, i appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

It's your for loop that is breaking your code.
Let's assume you have 3 links

```
x.wav
y.mp3
z.m4a
```

The way you are searching is in a specific order: mp3, wav, then m4a. What you want to do is search to see if your result is contained in the array, not if it coincides with the index search

(ie: first href **MUST** end in .mp3)

To do so you want to do it like so:

```
function checkstuff() {
    i = 0;
    $("#tree ol li").each(function() {

      i++;
      console.log(i);
      var temp_val = $(this).children("a").attr("href");
      var temp_val2 = temp_val.substr(temp_val.length - 4);
      console.log(temp_val2);
      var extArr = [".mp3", ".wav", ".m4a"];
      if (extArr.indexOf(tempval2) > -1) {
        console.log(extArr.indexOf(tempval2) + "WELL this should have worked..");
        $(this).hide();
      };
    });
```

Comment: oh a simple mistake broke everything.. but thanks for the help!